# Child method is undefined for the type Base

Tags: java, inheritance

```
public class Base {
    public String Method1() {
        System.out.println("Inside Base method 1");
        return "";
    }
}
class Child extends Base {
    static Base o = null;
    public String Method1() {
        System.out.println("Inside Base method 1");
        return "";
    }
    public String Method2() {
        return "Cant be called with base reference";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Base base = new Child();
        base.Method1();
        base.Method2();***(Error : **The method Method2() is undefined for the type Base**)***
    }
}
```

As the code suggests I want to know, What actually happens in memory allocation that hides Base from calling extra methods of Child and what it is called
And is there a way of calling methods via Base.
Please help

Comment: You declare it as a Base so it's a Base, javac doesn't have a crystal ball

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771308/calling-child-methods-while-using-polymorphism-in-an-arraylist

Comment: @RC. Out of interest, why are you posting duplicates as comments like this and not as close votes?

Comment: @JoeC because if I vote close it the question is closed and this duplicate is "so so"

Answer (score 1):

`base.Method2()` is invalid because Base class has no method with that name, that is the meaning of the error

> *The method Method2() is undefined for the type Base*

since you are doing this:

```
Base base = new Child();
```

one option you have is casting, then you can call that method...

```
Base base = new Child();
base.Method1();
((Child) base).Method2();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to study more about how polymorphism works.
Your instance is a child, but you use it like a Base. Base knows nothing about his children, he only knows his methods.
Cast the instance to Child to acces their custom methods.

```
((Child)base).Method2()
```